# How does down casting quite work? C#

Tags: c#, programming-languages

If I instantiate an object like such :

```
Person hello = new Person();
```

I'm allowed to do something like

```
Employee test = (Employee)hello;
```

What does this do? What'd downcasting all about? So when we allocate memory for the base, and down cast what happens there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not work.  It will throw `InvalidCastException` at runtime. (assuming `Employee : Person`).

Answer (score 3):

You should be familiar with this [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

If we assume that class `Employee` extend `Person` and there is no implicit implementation  then at runtime it will throw `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you didn't specify [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) or [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) operator conversion from `Person` to `Employee` that will throw `InvalidCastException`.